# Oracle procedure sample with datatable as input parametere

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, oracle, stored-procedures

Any body know how write oracle stored procedure data table as input parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass a parameter as `varchar2`, then  build your query string and execute it with `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` or as a cursor. More examples [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg09dyn.htm)

UPDATE. Example:

```
create table temp11(id int not null);
/
create or replace
procedure test_proc(table_name varchar2)
as
  query_str varchar2(200);
  begin
  query_str := 'INSERT INTO '||table_name||'(id) values (2)';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE query_str ;

end;
/
exec test_proc('temp11');
commit;
```

Comment: hi a1ex07 thanks for reply, actually i had to insert entire table data in to data base using insert query then how can i write stored procedure. any sample plz post it.

Comment: @Sreedhar goud: Check example.

Answer (score 0):

It's very common in these cases to use database temporary tables. Meaning that you insert the datatable records into the table and call your procedure without closing the connection, so that it sees the temporary data and process it.

The pseudo code would like this:

```
//Get the data you want to process
DataTable data = GetData();

//Create new Connection
Connection conn = Connection.CreateNew();

//Open the connection
conn.Open()

//Insert the data on a temporary table using the open connection
InsertDataIntoTemporaryTable(conn, data);

//Call the procedure to process the data using the same open connection
CallProcedureToProcessData(conn);

//Finish by ending the connection (everything done in the procedure will be commited)
conn.Close();
```

Another implementable option is to build the procedure with a CLOB parameter where the application would pass all the datatable records concatenated with a field and row delimiter. The procedure would have to split it the two ways and form a better structure, like a table of record formed by a table of varchar2.

Comment: sample examples any mention plz

Comment: Sure, I could add an example i think. Haven't you found the solution already tho?

Comment: Ya i didn't found the solution if you have a solution post it.

Comment: i didn't understand what your doing i understand up to get datatable and open connection but not InsertDataIntoTemporaryTable() is it a predefined method in c#.

Comment: Have you read my answer entirely? The solution i proposed involves a database temporary table, it is a table where the records are persisted while the connection is still open. The pseudo code i posted tells you each step you would have to implement to make it work, it is not real code, those are not real classes, that is my imaginary representation of how the code would probably become.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example to copy one row from `EMPLOYEES` to `EMPLOYEES_COPY`. 
I hope it will help you.

```
DROP TABLE EMPLOYEES;
/
DROP TABLE EMPLOYEES_COPY; 
/
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEES
(
  ID INT,
  FIRST_NAME varchar(30),
  LAST_NAME varchar(30)
);

insert into EMPLOYEES values(1,'AA','BBB');
insert into EMPLOYEES values(2,'CC','GGG');
insert into EMPLOYEES values(3,'EEE','MMM');
insert into EMPLOYEES values(4,'FFF','ZZZ');
/
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEES_COPY 
(
  ID INT,
  FIRST_NAME varchar(30),
  LAST_NAME varchar(30)
);
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE EMPLOYEE as 
type t_cursor is ref cursor;
procedure GETALL(curEMPLOYEE out t_cursor);
procedure INSERT_COPY;
end EMPLOYEE;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY EMPLOYEE as
  ---------------------------------------------
 procedure GETALL(curEMPLOYEE out t_cursor) as
   begin
      open curEMPLOYEE  for SELECT id, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME
                           FROM   EMPLOYEES;    
   end GETALL;
 ---------------------------------------------
 procedure INSERT_COPY as
   cur t_cursor;
   emp employees%rowtype;
   begin
      GETALL(curEMPLOYEE=>cur);
        LOOP
    FETCH cur INTO emp;
       EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND;
       insert into EMPLOYEES_COPY
       values(emp.id,emp.FIRST_NAME,emp.LAST_NAME);
   END LOOP;
   end INSERT_COPY;   
end EMPLOYEE;
/
```

Packages are very useful, because you can group function of a single entity. In example, I have grouped function working on employees.

You can test an example using:

```
BEGIN      
  EMPLOYEE.INSERT_COPY;  
  commit;      
END;
```

More informations

- [Ref cursors](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/using-ref-cursors-to-return-recordsets.php)
- [Packages](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96624/09_packs.htm)

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578515/how-to-insert-result-set-returned-by-an-oracle-stored-procedure-into-another-tab/12607979#12607979) is similar problem.

Comment: thanks for reply Parado, but i am not doing database table to database table i am sending it form my application to procedure to execute.